# how much cheaper would the J Web Telescope be per unit if economies of scale were applied in the creation of a complete industrial complex on Luna?

Tags: james-webb-telescope, reduced-gravity-manufacturing

very few items are manufactured as expensively as space based hardware for a lot of good reasons, yet one of those reasons can be fixed. if standard industrial practices such as, intermodal shipping, mass production, & standardization are developed on Luna, more equipment could be made available at a fraction of the cost while increasing the benefits of expanding human space based operations. every produced item has what is known as a set up cost. this cost is more often than not greater than the material cost or the fabrication time. this is because it takes less effort to make each unit than it does to get ready to do so. the cost of shipping equipment is so expensive that it justifies great effort to reduce the cost in order to acquire access to the benefits of space. don't get me started on how it will aide our implementation of astroponics. (astroponics, intermodal transport, & mass-production are not an invention of mine nor are they at all new ideas unless you are on an internet forum dedicated to space engineering.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: An entire lunar industrial base dedicated entirely to the production of JWST-equivalent space telescopes? I think you just came up with a way to make the JWST look like a bargain. As unfocused as it is, the question suggests some misconceptions about why the JWST was as expensive as it was. Being a one-off was only a small part of it, and being built on Earth was basically irrelevant to the cost.

Comment: 1) Welcome to SE Space Exploration. 2) Please consider editing the question so it is not a wall of text. 3) The use of a capital letter at the start of each sentence would improve readability. 4) To dispel any misconceptions, all Stack Exchange sites are question & answer sites, they are not forums, which are about discussion.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff JWST is intended as an example of a principle poorly understood in spaceflight to date, yet well understood in virtually every other industry. how can you possibly say that (240 tons) of LH² & LOX are irrelevant to the cost? I could See if you meant the slightly less than 3 tons of hydrazine for the JWST itself but that hardly touches fuel cost At roughly $170.0907*107=$97049 give or take versus 240 tons at(?)6:1or4:1 $3.66 per kg for liquid hydrogen. oxygen at 67 cents per gallon.$0.16 per kg for liquid oxygen

Comment: Hi Stellar Nomad, welcome to Space SE. I support Fred's comments and also the initial community bot comment. I see you are interested both in the economies of scale and the "in-principle" benefits of in-space fabrication. These are both laudable ideas but with such timescales that it would probably help to separate the notions into different questions. Short of that its hard for a respondent to see what would make a helpful answer.

Comment: A potential stepping stone to the economies of scale topic would be to consider Starlink rather than JWST, but of course costs are not known outside of SpaceX. OneWeb and Iridium being slightly less adventurous examples.

Comment: For in-space fabrication there are two routes a) the material still has to be launched from Earth, for which the only benefit is i) later commitment of the design or ii) circumventing the launch vibration and thus lessening the design challenge. Route b) is to use in-situ resources, which I presume is what you mean by Lunar. Someway along the path this will need a very clear notion of the inventory of raw materials to support product and process needs. It will have to start with the basics - again the JWST is not a great example because of the complexity of those needs.

Comment: @StellarNomad I can say that the propellant costs are irrelevant *because they are*. The Ariane 5 launch cost is about \$180 million. That's about a thousand times what the core's propellant costs. The SRB propellant is relatively expensive, but is no more than a few million in raw materials. SpaceX's Starship is intended to drastically reduce non-propellant costs, and propellant is still expected to be only 5-10% of the flight cost, perhaps 1-2% of the final price.

Answer (score 1):

The complete industrial complex on Luna will be so incredible expensive that the cost of another JWST will be very tiny in comparison.

A very well established and diversified industrial complex will be needed to produce only the heavier parts of another JWST. All computer parts for the telescope will be still manufactured on Earth.

Mining beryllium for the mirrors on the Moon and purifing it as neccessary will be very difficult and expensive.

Comment: Worse, the heaviest components of JWST are likely the cheapest: the mirrors, basic structural components, propellant tanks, etc. The expensive parts were the complex parts, expensive due to the skilled labor involved in constructing and testing them (which was made worse by poor allocation of mass budgets that made the sunshield particularly delicate and complicated). Labor is not cheaper on the moon.